# Difference/comparison of two different sized sets of data

Tags: time-series, curves

I have the data of two different devices (a and b) measuring the same outcome along the time. These results are approximate but have different values. I would like to assess the variation/agreement between them.

So, device **a** is the reference and device **b** is expected to have similar result. The measurements were performed within approximate duration, however the size of each sample is different:

a_data=[time_a,mag_a] % lenght of 116 measurements

b_data=[time_b,mag_b] % lenght of 106 measurements

What is the best way to determine this difference of measurements. First consideration was comparing the overall Area Under the Curve (AUC) of each device. Secondly, interpolate one of the samples for matching the time points and sample sizes (both with 116 measurments) and directly calculate the difference (and total mean(SD)) and/or compare applying Bland-Altman test.

I have searched, however I don't know the proper mathematical approach for this comparison/assessment.

I have attached an graph with the data example.

Can you help me?

thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: A (dis)similarity metric?

Comment: Yes. How to analyze and report properly. As statistical analysis of the difference....

Comment: If you only want a distance measure you can use one of the popular metrics such as Manhattan or Euclidean distance.